# Transferring a user to a bot when joining a channel

Tags: python, bots, telegram, channel, aiogram

How can I make it so that when a user is asked to join a channel, they are transferred to a chat with a bot?

It is necessary that when clicking on the link to the closed telegram channel, the user clicks "Join", a request to join is sent, and when clicking on the button, the user is transferred to a chat with a bot. Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to implement this?

No, as of today Telegram does not provide any functionality to do this.

A chat with a bot can only be opened by the direct bot-username t.me link, for example https://t.me/my_fancy_bot. But it's not possible to a fallback like link to an non existing t.me link.

The only option would be to share the t.me link with the bot username.